# Apple watch app does not work when iPhone app is in terminated state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on an apple watch app, but facing a weird issue, i.e. my watch app works only when I manually open the iPhone app or when iPhone app is in background. When I terminate my iPhone app and test apple watch app then it does not work any more.

Here I am mentioning watch app flow:

- When apple watch app starts, I call a web api to fetch response from server.
- I used `openParentApplication:reply:` method to call web api from parent app
- I understand that, I will have to call web api method in a background thread because, openParentApplication:reply: method automatically open the parent app in iPhone and suspends in a mean time, so if we are processing a time taking task using this method then we should use a background thread as mentioned under [WatchKit Development Tips](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/). So I am using a background thread to call web api.
- When I get response I pass it to watch app.

Here is the attached snippet:

**Watch App - InitialInterfaceController.m**

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
}

- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    [self getDetails];
}


- (void)getDetails{
    //Open parent app
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@“request”:@“details”}
                                           reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
                                               if (!error) {
                                                   NSLog(@“Success”);
                                                   [self parseKPI:replyInfo];
                                               }
                                               else{
                                                   NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                               }
                                           }];

}
```

**iPhone App - AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
              reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply{
    NSString *request = [userInfo objectForKey:@“request”];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        // Get Details
        if ([request isEqualToString:@"details"]) {
            APIHandler *api = [[APIHandler alloc] init];
            [api getDetailsUsername:@“my_user_name”
                          onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *details) {
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              reply(details);
                          });

                      } onFailure:^(NSString *message) {
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              reply(@{@"Error":message});
                          });

                      }];
        }
}
```

**iPhone App - APIHandler.m**

```
- (void) getDetailsUsername:(NSString *)username
             onSuccess:(void(^)(NSDictionary * details))success
             onFailure:(void(^)(NSString *message))failure{

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST, DETAILS_API];
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?username=%@",username];
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"&%@", self.APIKeyParameter];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *mutableURL = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:mutableURL
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                                   if (!connectionError) {
                                       NSError *error = nil;
                                       NSDictionary *details = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                                                                 error:&error];
                                       success(details);
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       failure(@"Connection Error!");
                                   }
                               }];
}
```

But this approach is not working for me.

I found one more issue in watch app simulator i.e.
 `- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context` for my initial view controller is called, but `- (void)willActivate` method is not being called sometimes and I just see watch app spinner. Some times it works. It’s quite strange. I have around 15 controls (including all groups) in initial interface controller added using storyboard.

I have also referred [Watchkit not calling willActivate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083727/watchkit-not-calling-willactivate-method) and modified my code but still facing same issue.

Can any one let me know why is this issue persisting in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to handle the request in the iPhone app a bit differently in order for your app to not be killed off by the OS. I've shared a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848521/3704092